# Working with app in windows background via Pywinauto

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

### Good day!!

The question is to understand how Windows processors work when folded.
Closer to the point!

### Tools

python3 (keyboard,pywinauto), win10-64bit

### Task

There is a program, it is minimized in the third window. The whole GUI is an input, a submit button, and determining the network status( Online, Disconnect, Ready, Wait )
Through pywinauto I read the status, and if necessary, enter data through the keyboard

### Problem

The program works fully when the application is visually displayed, but as soon as it is in the third window, then pywinauto becomes inactive. Doesn't even work method set_focus()

### Some Code

"Crutch" which I use so that the departure is not in a collapsed position

```
from pywinauto.timings import Timings
Timings.window_find_timeout = 120
```

Application initialization

```
    def __start_soft(self, path: str) -> pywinauto.Application:
        print(f"Soft Started... {self.user_named_App}")
        pywinauto.Application(backend="uia").start(path)
        return pywinauto.Application(backend="uia").connect(path=path, visible_only=False)
```

Access to status

```
status: pywinauto.Application.WindowSpecification =
self.active_App.AccountingTimeArrival.child_window(
auto_id="58464", control_type="StatusBar" ).Static
```

### Thoughts

I am well aware that I am not that strong in programming, but looking at other applications, I know that there is some way to interact with the application in a minimized form. However, I think that pywinauto is able to interact directly with the GUI. Perhaps there are alternative methods to solve this problem. I will be glad to any criticism and answers, more experienced users!

Comment: pywinauto has silent methods to interact with minimized window. It's not guaranteed to always work as it depends on application. For example, `backend="win32"` method like `.send_chars()` and `.send_keystrokes()` may work without setting a focus for window. Also it's good to know what do you mean under "the program is in the third window". Some screenshot from `Inspect.exe` could be useful.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Due to NDA I can't provide screencast Inspect.exe
But using win32 is inconvenient on 64-bit windows. However, the application gui is written in 32-bit.
The tool is quite powerful, but the problem with the background is serious. But I also wondered, perhaps the application's GUI itself is badly designed?
Here is a bug that affects the use of 32win.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov UserWarning: 32-bit application should be automated using 32-bit Python (you use 64-bit Python)
  warnings.warn(

Comment: @AnnaBrown Try executing your program from cmd. Make sure your cmd is running as administrator this is the key.

Comment: `backend="win32"` doesn't mean it's 32-bit. It's a short name of Win32 API which is actual for 64-bit Windows and apps as well. But yes, 32-bit apps is better to automate using 32-bit Python to avoid some memory sizes mismatch with unpredictable effects. For `backend="uia"` usually there is no matter it is 32-bit or 64-bit app.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov After rewriting the code a bit, it worked with win32 backend. Now I consider myself a little stupid. Last question, why then py64 is not suitable for the task of this library?

Comment: `backend="win32"` uses some C structures inside. And these structures are used both in pywinauto and application. So if the structure is aligned for 64-bit, 32-bit application may crash because it expects different sizes of fields.

Comment: If you don't know what is "C structure", it means you need to learn C language basics to understand it better. pywinauto uses Win32 API functions from OS libraries like `user32.dll` and `kernel32.dll`. And these libraries are written in C language, of course. Fortunately Python code can call C functions using standard Python module `ctypes`. Hope it's enough level of details for now. :)

Comment: May I ask you to post your own answer and accept it (by left side check box)? It's polite to mark the question as answered for others.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thank you very much for your detailed question. I hope this topic will be of interest not only to me. Pywinauto has provided great features for Python!
Also, thanks for pointing out the Windows libraries. Already studied their API. I express my gratitude to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

The solution is to use backend=win32 to solve this problem. However, it is worth noting that libraries such as **keyboards** and **pynput** should not be used. In **pywinauto** as an example:

> app.send_chars()

An efficient way to use applications in the background. There are no better alternatives for my task.

Comment: Method `send_chars()` is a method of a control, not a method of `Application` object. Just want to avoid confusing others on usage.